# ¿Cómo evitar que SQL Server me genere siempre los mismos registros cuando trabajo con números aleatorios?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de generar con SQL cadenas de carácteres aleatorios con el siguiente código:

```
select (
select string_agg(
     char(floor(rand(cast(newid() as varbinary))*62)+33),'')
from 
    Serie(10)) as password 
from 
    Serie(10)
```

Siendo Serie la siguiente función:

```
create function Serie(@size int)
returns @serie table(valor int)
as 
begin
declare @indice int=1
while(@indice<=@size)
    begin
        insert into @serie values(@indice)
        set @indice=@indice+1
    end
return
end
```

El problema que tengo es que siempre genera la misma cadena. Adjunto imagen de prueba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mismo código en MariaDB(con su sintaxis correspondiente) funciona perfectamente, y genera una cadena diferente en cada registro.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que genere una cadena diferente para cada registro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para empezar,la función que tienes es terriblemente ineficiente. Lo ideal es cambiarla por algo que funciona decenas de veces más rápido. Para aprender más de esto, te recomiendo leer acerca de tablas de números (*[tally tables](https://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/)* en inglés) y como reemplazan los bucles.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SERIE(@SIZE INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@size) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n AS valor
FROM cteTally

GO
```

Después podemos ver el problema y es que estás creando la contraseña con 10 caracteres y después repitiendo ese valor diez veces. Lo que intentas hacer se puede hacer con una simple llamada a la función y agrupando los valores de forma sencilla.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(
     CHAR(FLOOR(RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY))*62)+33),'')
FROM 
    Serie(100)
GROUP BY valor % 10
```

Por cierto, no necesitas usar RAND puesto que la función NEWID ya te da un valor aleatorio. Solo necesitas usar CHECKSUM para obtener un valor entero a partir de eso y ABS para mantenerlo positivo.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG( CHAR( ABS( CHECKSUM( NEWID()))%62 + 33),'')
FROM 
    Serie(100)
GROUP BY valor % 10
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis, era justo lo que quería. Voy a revisar minuciosamente el artículo sobre las tablas que indicas. Ya había leído sobre ellas, pero siéndote sincero, nunca las había utilizado. Viendo el resultado que has expuesto, les prestaré toda la atención que se merecen. Mil gracias por tu contribución. Me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: De nada, son una herramienta muy útil una vez que entiendes como funcionan y su posible aplicación que no solo depende de los números sino el hecho de crear las filas. Por otro lado, también agregué una opción alternativa para generar los valores aleatorios. Revisa cual opción te conviene más.

Comment: Impresionante Luis. Muchas gracias. Una respuesta de premio. Tomo nota de esa nueva forma de generar números aleatorios. La había visto en alguna página, pero no la había utilizado nunca.